# ¿Cómo enviar Email de Bienvenida al Registrar Usuario en PHP?

Tags: php, mysqli, php7, phpmailer, mailer

Tengo un formulario que usa un `script` escrito en `PHP` para registrar en una base de datos `MySQL` **nombre, razónSocial, representante, contraseña, cuenta de e-mail, etc.** que se encuentran en el formulario. Ya pude realizar una conexión con la base de datos para registrar esos datos pero ahora necesito complementar esto con el envío de un correo electrónico de bienvenida con los datos del usuario que se registró al **e-mail** que los usuarios coloquen en el formulario de registro.

He leído sobre la función `mail()` de `PHP` pero quisiera saber como hacer dicha función que utilice la variable de correo electrónico que registró el usuario para enviarle el correo automáticamente cuando se haga <kbd>click</kbd> en el botón tipo `input` enviar, se ejecute el `script` de envío de correo electrónico y el que ya tengo que conecta con la base de datos para registrar los datos.

Espero su colaboración. Este es mi código para ingresar los datos y las variables que hacen la lectura y la función de `PHPMAILER`. Saludos.

```
<?php
require 'funcs/conexion.php';

$nombreEmpresa = $_POST['nombre_empresa'];
$razonSocial = $_POST['razon_social'];
$representanteLegal = $_POST['representante_legal'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$numeroEmpleados = $_POST['numero_empleados'];
$rangoEmpleados = $_POST['rango_empleados'];
$estado = $_POST['estado'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO empresasregistradas (nombre_empresa, razon_social, 
representante_legal, email, numero_empleados, rango_empleados, estado) 
VALUES ('$nombreEmpresa', '$razonSocial', '$representanteLegal', '$email', 
'$numeroEmpleados', '$rangoEmpleados', '$estado')";
$resultado = $mysqli->query($sql); 

function enviarEmail($email, $nombre, $asunto, $cuerpo){
require_once("PHPMailer-5.2.11/PHPMailerAutoload.php");

    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->Port = '587';

    $mail->Username = 'MICUENTA@gmail.com';
    $mail->Password = 'MIPASSWORD';

    $mail->setFrom('MICUENTA@gmail.com', 'MI NOMBRE');
    $mail->addAddress($email, $nombre);

    $mail->Subject = $asunto;
    $mail->Body    = $cuerpo;
    $mail->IsHTML(true);

    if($mail->send())
    return true;
    else
    return false;
  }
  ?>
```

Comment: Aparentemente solo te falta la llamada a la funcion `enviarEmail()`. No me queda claro cual es el problema exactamente

Comment: @Xerif, Creo que tienes que leer con mas calma lo que esta pidiendo el compañero, Por otra cosa creo que te funcionaria si recuperas el id del registro insertado y haces una consulta de nuevo usando ese id recuperado.

Comment: Al momento en el que se hace el registro puedes tomar el id y hacer una consulta trayendo la información del usuario que acabas de insertar, llamas al metodo `enviarEmail()` con los parametros

Comment: Hola amigo DaxTter77, cómo irían y en que orden? Es decir lo tengo que hacer en este mismo PHP dónde leo el POST? y que tendría que hacer con el Método enviarEmail();?

Comment: @SuriGang'sHallen el método creo que está bien, la cuestión es el contenido que le vas a mandar en el correo, para eso puedes hacer un `template` en un `.html` y en ese mismo `php` o puedes llamar ese método que tienes ahí y por los parametros le mandas el correo, teniendo en cuenta de que lo recibes todo por post, pues no es necesario hacer la consulta, pero sí prefieres hacerlo, no está mal

Comment: De igual manera, sí tienes un host, es bueno que quieras usar el `mail()` pero sino, y si no quieres hacer mucho cambio, dejalo de esa manera

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías eliminar la función `enviarmail()` que no está prestando ninguna utilidad.

Lo otro, habilitar tu cuenta de Gmail para usar el servidor SMTP, ya que cuando se quiera autentificar, no te dejará.

Te sugiero modificar al final:

```html
<?php
require 'funcs/conexion.php';

$nombreEmpresa = $_POST['nombre_empresa'];
$razonSocial = $_POST['razon_social'];
$representanteLegal = $_POST['representante_legal'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$numeroEmpleados = $_POST['numero_empleados'];
$rangoEmpleados = $_POST['rango_empleados'];
$estado = $_POST['estado'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO empresasregistradas (nombre_empresa, razon_social, 
representante_legal, email, numero_empleados, rango_empleados, estado) 
VALUES ('$nombreEmpresa', '$razonSocial', '$representanteLegal', '$email', 
'$numeroEmpleados', '$rangoEmpleados', '$estado')";
$resultado = $mysqli->query($sql); 

require_once("PHPMailer-5.2.11/PHPMailerAutoload.php");
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();

$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;

$mail->Username = "TUCORREO@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "TU CLAVE";
$mail->setFrom('TUCORREO@gmail.com', 'TU NOMBRE');
$mail->addAddress($email, $representanteLegal);
$mail->Subject = 'BIENVENIDO '.$nombreEmpresa;
$mail->Body = 'Gracias por Registrarse';

if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Error en Mensaje: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Mensaje Enviado";
};
?>
```

Prueba si te funciona

Comment: Es importante y de ayuda para la comunidad agregues una explicación del código, revisa [answer], y edita tu respuesta, saludos.

Comment: GRACIAS POR TÚ APORTE , ESA FUE LA SOLUCIÓN

Answer (score 0):

Fijate que aunque la función está bien redactada, no la estás ejecutando en ningún momento...

Puedes agregar una línea como la siguiente después de insertar el registro a la base de datos:

```
enviarEmail($email, $nombre, 'Bienvenido/a', 'Gracias por registrarse en el sistema');
```

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow en Español, te sugiero que revises bien la pregunta, ya que tu respuesta no está respondiendo a lo que pide el usuario, te recomiendo que leas también [Cómo responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), por otro lado haz el [Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que consigas tu primera [medalla!](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)